# Monads and do notation

Tags: haskell, state, monads

If we have following code:

```
import Control.Monad.State  

type Stack = [Int]

pop :: State Stack Int  
pop = state $ \(x:xs) -> (x,xs)  

push :: Int -> State Stack ()  
push a = state $ \xs -> ((),a:xs)  

stackManip :: State Stack Int  
stackManip = do  
    push 3  
    x <- pop  
    pop
```

Which we run with:

```
command: runState stackManip [1]  
result: (1,[])
```

How does 'Haskell' know to give our 'x' the value 3?
So, how does he know to take 3 and not the state(stack in this case) out of the State monad?

The same question with a Maybe monad:

```
do
 x <- Just 5
```

There is only one value here, but how does Haskell know to take the '5' and give it to 'x'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes down to the definition of `>>=`.  You should note that `do` --- for the features used here --- is just thin syntax sugar for a call to `>>=`:

```
do
   x <- pop
   pop
= pop >>= \ x -> pop
```

and (ignoring newtype wrappers) `>>=` is defined for `State` as:

```
a >>= f = \ s -> case a s of
    (x, s') -> f x s'
```

So `f` gets the result as its first argument (the one named `x`) and the state as its (silent) second argument (the one inside the definition of `pop`).

Note that you can't define `>>=` the other way around:

```
a >>= f = \ s -> case a s of
    (x, s') -> f s' x
```

because then it would have type

```
State s a -> (s -> State a b) -> State a b
```

which has the wrong distribution of type variables through the type.  (This is why Haskell prefers single-letter type variables: which type variables are the same matters a lot more than what they actually mean).

Comment: Just to make this clearer: `do` notation is syntactical sugar, which makes using `>>=` and `>>` repeatedly much clearer and prettier.

Comment: @AJFarmar - correct, although the pattern-matching version `do (x:xn) <- a; f x xn` is substantially more complicated.  Hence I limit my remarks to the version where there's a variable on the left-hand side of the `<-`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `x <- pop` roughly takes `x` from `pop`. The `pop` operation returns `3`, and not the whole stack. You can also see that from the type:

```
pop :: State Stack Int   -- returns Int, keeps Stack as state
```

By comparison, `get` has the type:

```
get :: State Stack Stack  -- returns Stack, keeps Stack as state
```

so, `x <- get` would get the whole state stack.

If you want to have a more detailed explanation, I would recommend you look at how `(>>=)` is defined for the `State Stack` monad. Then, apply it to your code, after having desugared it as

```
push 3  >>= ( \ _ ->
pop     >>= ( \ x ->
pop ))
```

After many simplifications, you should reach something similar to:

```
State (\stack0 ->  let (_, stack1) = unState (push 3) stack0
                       (x, stack2) = unState pop      stack1
                       (_, stack3) = unState pop      stack2
                       in stack3 )
```

Then, you can inline `push` and `pop` and keep on simplifying, if you wish. But you already see above where the `x` is coming from.

Comment: pop :: State Stack Int   -- returns Int, keeps Stack as state ||
If you say 'returns Int', wouldn't the function type read something like this: State Stack -> Int ? How I read it now is that the pop function returns a whole State with Stack and Int.

Comment: You should also note that push is also a function that returns "the whole State with Stack and Int"  One of the appeals of do notation is that it hides the messy details and allows you to focus on the happy path.

Comment: @Gert-Jan Note that `State s a` is defined as `data State s a = State (s -> (a,s))`, so it is a regular function boxed inside a constructor. This function takes the old state and produces the result (e.g. an Int) and a new state.